# How to configure using plugins in DHTMLX gantt in an angular project

Tags: angular, plugins, dhtmlx

I am trying to use marker plugin in my dhtmlxGantt used in angular poject using documentation in https://dhtmlx.com/blog/dhtmlx-gantt-chart-usage-angularjs-2-framework/. I am trying to display a vertical line for the current date in gantt. But the marker plugin doesn't work.

I did add the below code in ngOnInit in my angular component

```
gantt.plugins({ 
      marker: true 
  });
```

and then added a marker

```
var today = new Date("04-04-2018");

  var markerId = gantt.addMarker({      
      start_date: today, 
      text: "todaynew",
  });
```

and have defined the todaynew in .css file as below

```
.todaynew{
    background: #ffb121;
  }
```

But the vertial marker for the current day doesn't appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to suggest what might be wrong. Please send a ready Angular demo.

Here is an Angular demo where it works correctly:
https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/7c03a81b247bcd8e512a32d79157618f/angular7+marker_7.0.5_gpl.zip